# References of an operator $T: V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras, hecke-algebras, braided-tensor-categories

Let $V$ be a vector space with a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ and let $X_{ij} = v_i \otimes v_j$. Then $X_{ij}, i,j=1,\ldots, n$, is a basis of $V \otimes V$. Let $T: V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$ be the linear operator defined by
\begin{align}
& T(X_{ij}) = q^{-\delta_{ij}}X_{ji}, \\
& T(X_{ji}) = q^{\delta_{ij}} X_{ij} - (q-q^{-1})X_{ji},
\end{align}
where $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$. Then $T$ satisfies $(T-q^{-1})(T+q)=0$ and $T_{12}T_{23}T_{12} = T_{23}T_{12}T_{23}$. The operator $T$ is on page 26 of [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.4357v3.pdf). Are there some other references about this operator $T$? Thank you very much.

Edit: here $q$ is a non-zero complex number.

Comment: As someone not familiar with quantum algebra, what is the "q" here?  Also, is the first line a definition, and the second line an equivalent expression?  In other words, is it obvious that $ q^{-\delta_{ji}}X_{ij} = q^{\delta_{ij}} X_{ij} - (q-q^{-1})X_{ji}$

Comment: @Steven Gubkin, thank you very much for your comments. I edited the post.

Comment: @Steven Gubkin, the first line of the definition of $T$ is for $T(X_{ij})$ and the second line is for $T(X_{ji})$, $i \leq j$. But it is slightly strange since for $i<j$, we have $T(X_{ij})=0$.

Comment: For people who haven't followed the link and find the equations dense, this is just the braiding for the standard representation of quantum sl(n) in its usual basis.

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is.  The paper gives several references to a paper of Jimbos, and this is material that would be covered by most textbooks on quantum groups.  Have you tried looking at Jimbo's paper?  Have you read any textbooks on quantum groups?  A keyword that might help you in finding material is "R-matrix".

Comment: @Noah Snyder, I tried to find the formulas of $T$ in the books of Kassel, Chari & Pressley, Majid, and Klimyk & Schmudgen. But I didn't find the formulas. Could you please give a hint that which chapters of the books should I look at? Thank you very much.

Comment: In Chari and Pressley it's Section 10.2.

Comment: @Noah Snyder, in Chari and Pressley, Section 10.2, page 335, I found the R matrix: $$ R_{\epsilon} = \left( \begin{matrix} \epsilon & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon - \epsilon^{-1} & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \epsilon \end{matrix} \right). $$ But the matrix for $T$ is $$ \left( \begin{matrix} q^{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -(q-q^{-1}) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & q^{-1} \end{matrix} \right).  $$ They are different.

Comment: @Noah Snyder, I made a mistake. The matrix of $T$ is $$ \left( \begin{matrix} q^{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -(q-q^{-1}) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & q^{-1} \end{matrix} \right). $$

Comment: Note the braiding is R composed with swap.  That explains why the middle 2-by-2 is different.  Otherwise it's just signs and conventions.